# How to make main project to use libs built from other projects in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, static-libraries, linker-errors, projects-and-solutions

Actually, question was set in the Theme of the message. But yet again,

i have Solution with 3 projects, two of whitch are Static libraries and one is Application. How my Application project could know from where to pull these .libs.

Yeh, i can do it from Linker->Input->Additional libraries, but i think there are must be other way if projects are in one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way, works on VS2010 and up.  Right-click your EXE project, Properties, Common Properties, Framework and References.  Click the `Add New Reference` button and select your project that generates the .lib.  Repeat as necessary.

This does *two* things, it takes care of the Additional Dependencies linker setting, automatically adding the output of the library project.  And it ensures that projects are built in the right order, normally something you'd have to with the Project Dependencies command.  In your given example, with enough machine horsepower, the library projects will build concurrently.  And the main project won't start building until they are both done.